# joining Ksql table and stream returns null

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

i'm using confluent-5.1.4 ksql and i built a stream from another stream with below code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI4yR.png)

as you may noticed the new stream is partitioned by the 'streamalertkey' field value

i created a table to save historical data with the following command:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J58LM.png)

i want to join stream with table by the 'tablealertkey' field in my table and 'streamalertkey' in my stream

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq7PI.png)

as you can see the keys are available in both stream and table but when i want to left join the stream and table together it returns null for table values as you can see in the below image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUwaC.png)

i limited the results to show just one row but it returns null for all rows

and last thing to mention is that i created the table and mentioned that i want it to be partitioned by tablealertkey field but the ksql generates this key automatically

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AP0rT.png)

could anyone explain why the left join doesn't happen and why it returns null?

i guessed that when ksql want to do join it joins the partitions that are in the same worker node and when the both data are not in the same node it returns null.i tried to repatriation the table again by the tablealertkey field but ksql generates the same key again